# simple Azure website (built with nodejs), how to log http get request

Tags: node.js, azure, express

I have a simple Azure website (free or shared) which is built with nodejs/expressjs. There is no local or database storage.

I'd like to save incoming http/get request for further analysis. I guess I can't just save `req` to the local drive/json temp file.

Is there a way to save to some log file that I can ftp download later?

simpler and less cost, the better.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
fs = require('fs');

function homePage(req, res){
    var d = new Date();
    var logDate = d.getTime();
    fs.writeFile(logDate+'.txt', req, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('Logged');
    });
}
```

So the first line we call node's file system as a requirement. Then we write a homepage route that created a date variable to use as the log's file name. After that we use fs to write the request to the file.

You'll need to do some tinkering to optimize readability but this'll get you started. File's shouldn't overwrite since we used the time, but it might overwrite if you get huge traffic.

Comment: Isn't it true that Azure (website) with discard any local file? Or it's safe to save such log files locally, as long as it's within some size limits. I only have one instance running btw.

Comment: I am not 100% sure on Azure. It shouldn't, since technically your JavaScript is a local file. It's easy enough to write in, that I would try it and see if it works.